# Accessing Scala standalone singleton object from Java

Tags: java, scala, singleton, scala-java-interop

I am having trouble accessing the method fromString in Scala. I tried javap and at least one of the ways i am accessing should be working, but its not.

App.scala

```
object App { 
 def fromString(s:String) : Option[Int] =  if( s == "0" ) Some(0) else None
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
           //THEY ALL GIVE COMPILER ERRORS
           //App.fromString("");
           //App$.fromString("") ;
           //App$.MODULE$.fromString("");

    }
}
```

JAVAP OUTPUTS

javap App
Compiled from "App.scala"

```
public final class App extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final scala.Option fromString(java.lang.String);
}
```

javap App$
Compiled from "App.scala"

```
public final class App$ extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public static final App$ MODULE$;
    public static {};
    public scala.Option fromString(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `App.MODULE$.fromString("");` so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it in Eclipse, and the expected

```
App.fromString("");
```

compiles fine. Eclipse shows an error "App cannot be resolved", but I've learnt to ignore Eclipse's errors.

Maybe you haven't put your classes in the same package?

Comment: Huh, how silly. I have not yet learnt to ignore errors in Eclipse.